# DEQUEUE Oracle Advanced Queue from Weblogic Server

Tags: java, oracle, jms, advanced-queuing

I need to dequeue a Message from Oracle Advanced Queue (ADQ) through an MDB. The MDB is deployed on Weblogic 11. I can define a Foreign Server for ADQ ([official oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13738/aq_jms.htm)).

The qustion is:

**what happens if the payload is not a jms type 
e.g.
`queue_payload_type=>'sys.aq$_jms_text_message'`
but is a custom type?
How Weblogic remap it?**

Answer (score 1):

AQ supports different types of jms messages, and the mdb can check the type of the message and take diff actions. If you are expecting only txt messages but the content of the message is different the mdb needs to check that in its code.

Comment: T2u acharya, but what happens when the type is Not a jms message ? Weblog ignore it or try a remap?

Comment: I think weblogic will throw exception something like "oracle.jms.AQjmsException: JMS-108: Messages of type TextMessage not allowed with Destinations containing ..."

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to dequeue from a custom type through an MDB. To connect Weblogic to an AQ you need a `jms type`.

Alternatively AQ messages can be propagated and consumed using popular programming 
interfaces (API) such as PL/SQL, C/C++, Java and Visual Basic.

Then you can propoagate from an AQ custom type to an AQ "jms type".

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87861_01/NT817EE/appdev.817/a76938/adq_aex4.htm

But it will introduce a little bit of latency https://community.oracle.com/thread/2190829?start=0&tstart=0.